# Gcc check whether the given class has operator+

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

I created a code below to test whether there is an operator+ overload for 2 classes:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct _has_plus_hlp {
    template<typename X, typename Y>
    static std::true_type _check(X&, Y&, decltype(std::declval<X>() + std::declval<Y>()) = {});
    static std::false_type _check(...);

    using type = decltype(_check(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<U>()));
};
template<typename X, typename Y>
constexpr bool has_plus_v = _has_plus_hlp<X, Y>::type::value; 

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << detail::has_plus_v<int, std::string> << std::endl;
    auto f = [](auto& a, auto& b) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << detail::has_plus_v<decltype(a), decltype(b)> << std::endl;
    };
    std::string str = "HELLO";
    int num = 5;
    f(num, str);
}
```

This is what I got for g++ (7.4.0):

> **false
>
>   true**

Whereas I expect both to be false as in case of clang:

> **false
>
>   false**

Did I got something wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. All I did was replace printing with `static_assert`ions, and gcc 7.4 accepts it without a hitch https://godbolt.org/z/Mv8uhz

Comment: With g++ 7.3.0 I got false both times.

Comment: With gcc-8.2 I do get `false\nfalse`: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/273f04befb832554

Comment: Note that this produces false for `int + int`.

Comment: @chris well spotted, OP is missing two `const`s: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d886f75b58f53ea6

Comment: Very strange.. I used gdb to debug the code above and result on g++ is that it always reports true.. any thoughts?

Comment: @YSC by adding const i got true, true now on gcc...

Comment: @Quest I get the correct output: https://godbolt.org/z/Edy1hJ. Note that the code in YSC's last link is for `int` and `int`, not `int` and `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original version doesn't work because `std::declval<>` returns an r-value and a regular reference can't bind to it. A fix is to bind to a forwarding reference:

```
static std::true_type _check(X&&, Y&&, decltype(std::declval<X>() + std::declval<Y>()) = {});
```

---

A slightly simpler version:

```
template<class T, class U>
auto has_plus_test(T&& t, U&& u) -> decltype(static_cast<void>(t + u), std::true_type{});

std::false_type has_plus_test(...);

template<class T, class U>
using has_plus = decltype(has_plus_test(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<U>()));

template<class T, class U>
constexpr bool has_plus_v = has_plus<T, U>::value;

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_plus_v<int, int> << '\n'; // Outputs true.
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_plus_v<int, std::string> << '\n'; // Outputs false.
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_plus_v<std::string, std::string> << '\n'; // Outputs true.
}
```

Comment: The first one didn't work out but changing that to `static auto _check(T&& t, U&& u) -> decltype(static_cast<void>(t + u), std::true_type{});` worked like a charm

Comment: @Quest It worked in https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26ec2e4ae285cba3

Comment: This worked for me as well but the problems started when I tried it in a lambda like here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7a253a511d93932 But now this thing works as well. Thank you very much!