# Please explain the following C++ syntax

Tags: c++

The code I'm about to present here is originally here:

[Gcc check whether the given class has operator+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57292886/gcc-check-whether-the-given-class-has-operator)

I did read about SFINAE, but this example is still very unclear to me. These things are never mentioned in literature.

Even though I would like to get an explanation for the entire code, the most confusing part is:

```
static std::true_type _check(X&, Y&, decltype(std::declval<X>() + std::declval<Y>()) = {});
```

_check is a static member function taking 3 arguments?

1. What is the point of the first argument, a reference to type X?
2. What is the point of the second argument, a reference to type Y?
3. decltype should return a type (I guess a type of result X + Y, whatever that is ). What is the point of that entire argument and what does it mean "={}" at the end?

Edit:
Even though I provided a link to the original code, nobody cares about it, so here is a copy/paste:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct _has_plus_hlp {
    template<typename X, typename Y>
    static std::true_type _check(X&, Y&, decltype(std::declval<X>() + std::declval<Y>()) = {});
    static std::false_type _check(...);

    using type = decltype(_check(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<U>()));
};
template<typename X, typename Y>
constexpr bool has_plus_v = _has_plus_hlp<X, Y>::type::value; 

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << detail::has_plus_v<int, std::string> << std::endl;
    auto f = [](auto& a, auto& b) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << detail::has_plus_v<decltype(a), decltype(b)> << std::endl;
    };
    std::string str = "HELLO";
    int num = 5;
    f(num, str);
}
```

Edit #2:
@john So, if there is no operator+ defined for these two arbitrary types, what happens in that line of code? Also, can we omit the '=' from the "={}"?

Comment: Is there perhaps a `template` header somewhere that you missed? If not, then we need the definitions of the classes `X` and `Y`.

Comment: "*I provided a link to the original code*" If you're asking a question about code, you are supposed to provide the code in the question, not behind a link. Even a link on this very site.

Comment: C++ Templates: The Complete Guide (2nd Edition)

Is a good book to read about these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to your question numbers.

1. To allow template argument deduction of `X` to occur when `_check` is called.
2. Similarly for `Y`.
3. To check that X + Y is not an error (i.e. that X+Y exists), and the "={}" is a default argument for the third parameter. So it doesn't have to be supplied when calling `_check`

EDIT

If there is no operator+ then the version of `_check` that returns `true_type` is removed, leaving only the version of `_check` that returns `false_type`, so `_has_plus_hlp<T,U>::type` will be `false_type`. That's the basic mechanism of SFINAE.